# JavaScript () following }

Tags: javascript

I am studying JavaScript and I sometimes see something like this

```
function functionname()
{
   // Some statements
} () ;
```

What does () following } mean?

Thanks a lot, experts on Stack Overflow

Comment: The same as `()` after any other function.

Comment: Well, the intention is probably to call the function immediately as the answers discuss. But, note that it's a SyntaxError in this snippet. A [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) as this appears to be cannot be followed immediately by `()`. However, a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) can (thus the `FE` in IIFE). This distinction is why there's often another set of parenthesis around the `function`, which force it to be an expression.

Answer (score 8):

That is an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). It is used to create a new scope. For example:

```
var x = 10;
(function() {
   var x = 5;
}());
alert(x); // still 10
```

All it does is define and call the function at the same time.

---

IIFEs are also used to "save" the value of a variable. For example, this code won't work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i ++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() { alert(i) }
}
```

Every button will alert the last index when you click it, because after the loop is done `i` is `buttons.length`. To fix it, you would use an IIFE:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i ++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = (function(i) {
        return function() {
            alert(i)
        }
    })(i)
}
```

---

[More info on IIFEs](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: More info on this.
http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @Doorknob I have another question. What would be the benefit of using this kind of function since it won't be reusable? (not callable from somewhere else)

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz If you only need to use it once.

Comment: @Doorknob then why would i need to create a function? I could do it without creating a function. Is there any performance benefit?

Comment: @Caner To create a new scope, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It calls the function.

```
var foo = function () { return 1; }();
alert(foo); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to define a function, when you do it like this ...

```
(function functionname(innerArguments){
   // Some statements;
})(outerArguments);
```

... the function is executed as soon as this piece of code is interpreted; 
its the same as:

```
function functionname(innerArguments){
   // Some statements;
};
functionname(outerArguments);
```

Comment: Note that these snippets aren't actually identical; the first one is interpreted as a function declaration and then a useless expression. Your first snippet defines the function but does not execute it.